# how to use python with JNI or C++ in android project

Tags: python, android, c++, android-ndk

I want to use python in my android application. But I do not want to use any framework like django or flask. So to achieve this functionality I decided to use c++ as a bridge between my android application and python. Because I have already used python with c++ in my past projects. Now I was trying the same method to use python in a c++ file which is a part of my android application but it is not working this time. When I try to build my app it throws an error.
**The Error Is:-**

```
config.py:- "io.h" file not found
```

Now let me describe what technique I am using to connect with python:-

I am using **pybind11** to make a connection between my c++ and python module for that I have created a named
"methodchannel.cpp" inside **app->src->main->cpp directory**
In this cpp directory I have:-

1. One CMakeLlists.txt file
2. One cpp file named="methodchannel.cpp"
3. A directory named = "modules"
4. A directory named = "externals"

In this "externals" directory at number 4 I have my resurces of python and pybind11 and In my "modules" directory I have my  python module or python script which will be used in my android project.
Here is my CPP or JNI code:-

```
#include "jni.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "externals\python\include/Python.h"
#include "externals\pybind11\include\pybind11\embed.h"
namespace py = pybind11;
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_example_methodchannel_MainActivity_00024Companion_getNum(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint num)                                                           
{
    // TODO: implement getNum()

    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    auto module = py::module::import("modules.module");
    auto func = module.attr("myfunc");
    int result = func(num).cast<int>();
    return 12 + result;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you are bundling a Python interpreter with your application. How does your CMakeLists.txt compile and embed Python? Also note that going via pybind11 is actually the long way round. Python supports several levels of [embedding APIs](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html) natively.

Comment: @Botje but these embedding APIs are too hard to maintain and use and they are very outdated too. That is why I am using pybind11 here . It is easy to use.

Comment: "too hard to use"? Did you look at the very high level embedding? It is not much harder to use than `eval`. Do you have an idea of what kind of integratino you're looking for? Regardless, if you insist on using pybind you still need to get Python to compile using CMake.